# Scraping Linkedin Job Requirements

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, linkedin-api

I am new to Python and I hope someone on here can help me. I am building a program as part of my learning to scrape information from linkedin job adverts. So far it has gone well however seem to have hit a brick wall with this particular issue. I am attempting to scrape the **full job description, including the qualifications**. I have identified the xpath for the description and am able to reference this via the following:

`desc_xpath = '/html/body/main/section/div[2]/section[2]/div'`

This gives me nearly all of the job description information, however does not include the **qualifications** section of a linkedin job profile. I extract the high level, wordy element of each job profile, however the further drill downs such as responsibilities, qualifications, extra qualifications do not seem to get pulled by this reference.

Is anybody able to help?

Kind regards

D

**Example Code**

````
driver.get('https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/view/etl-developer-at-barclays-2376164866/?utm_campaign=google_jobs_apply&utm_source=google_jobs_apply&utm_medium=organic&originalSubdomain=uk')

time.sleep(3)

#job description
jobdesc_xpath = '/html/body/main/section[1]/section[3]/div/section/div'

job_descs = driver.find_element_by_xpath(jobdesc_xpath).text

print(job_descs) ```
````

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: if i try and scrape the full description for the following job advert, i do not get the 
'what you will be doing'
'what we're looking for'
'skills that will help you in the role'
'where will you be working' sections.

Sure have updated the initial ask with some code snippets for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selenium struggles to get the text located in different sub-tags. You could try to use an html parser, such as BeautifulSoup. Try this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/view/etl-developer-at-barclays-2376164866/?utm_campaign=google_jobs_apply&utm_source=google_jobs_apply&utm_medium=organic&originalSubdomain=uk'
driver.get(url)
#Find the job description
job_desc = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="show-more-less-html__markup show-more-less-html__markup--clamp-after-5"]')
#Get the html of the element and pass into BeautifulSoup parser
soup = BeautifulSoup(job_desc.get_attribute('outerHTML'), 'html.parser')
#The parser will print each paragraph on the same line. Use 'separator = \n' to print each each paragraph on a new line and '\n\n' to print an empty line between paragraphs
soup.get_text(separator='\n\n')
```

Comment: There are no corresponding ids to pull the information using that reference unfortunately.

Comment: Do you have any other suggestions I could try?

Thanks :)

Comment: I have updated the answer. Let me know if this works.

Comment: Thank you so much! Works an absolute charm :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

```
    l, k = [], []
    o = {}
    for i in range(0,math.ceil(100/25)):

        res = requests.get(target_url.format(i))
        soup=BeautifulSoup(res.text,'html.parser')
        alljobs_on_this_page=soup.find_all("li")

        for x, ele in enumerate(alljobs_on_this_page):
            jobid = alljobs_on_this_page[x].find("div",{"class":"base-card"}).get('data-entity-urn').split(":")[3]
            l.append(jobid)

    

    for j, ele in enumerate(l):

        resp = requests.get(target_job_url.format(l[j]))
        soup=BeautifulSoup(resp.text,'html.parser')

        o["job_id"] = l[j]

        try:
            o["company_name"]=soup.find("div",{"class":"top-card-layout__card"}).find("a").find("img").get('alt')
        except:
            o["company_name"]=None

        try:
            o["job_title"]=soup.find("div",{"class":"top-card-layout__entity-info"}).find("a").text.strip()
        except:
            o["job_title"]=None

        try:
            o["seniority_level"]=soup.find("ul",{"class":"description__job-criteria-list"}).find("li").text.replace("Seniority level","").strip()
        except:
            o["seniority_level"]=None

        try:
            o["job_location"] = soup.find("span",{"class":"topcard__flavor topcard__flavor--bullet"}).text.strip()
        except:
            o["job_location"]=None

        # job_desc = o["job_location"] = soup.find("div",{"class":"show-more-less-html__markup show-more-less-html__markup--clamp-after-5"}).text

        k.append(o)
        o={}
     print(k)
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of xPath, I use CSS selectors since for me it's easier to use & understand.  I grabbed the whole section, you can parse the string.

```
driver.get('https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/view/etl-developer-at-barclays-2376164866/?utm_campaign=google_jobs_apply&utm_source=google_jobs_apply&utm_medium=organic&originalSubdomain=uk')

sleep(3)

#job description
#expand description section to expose the html
driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".show-more-less-html__button.show-more-less-html__button--more")[0].click()
#get the section that contains the job requirments
job_descs = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".show-more-less-html.show-more-less-html--more")[0]

print(job_descs.text)
```